# LOAD DATA from CSV skip rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I create a simple query to load .csv file to my MySQL DB, it looks like:

```
    $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$filePath."' 
            INTO TABLE r_vehicle_submodel 
            CHARACTER SET UTF8
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
            ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
            IGNORE 1 LINES ";
```

Sounds really general, nothing special. I throw it a .csv with 29 000 lines with sctructure as below:

```
07,"BENELLI","81","90"
08,"BETA","81","90"
09,"BMW","81","90"
10,"BUFFALO","81","90"
11,"CAGIVA","81","90"
12,"CCF","81","90"
13,"CPI","81","90"
```

With a table structure:

```
code(varchar(2)) UTF8
name(varchar(40)) UTF8
model_code(varchar(2)) UTF8
manufacturer_code(varchar(2)) UTF8
```

But from 29k lines only 14k is actualy imported to table. No error happens during this import, I see nothing corrupted in data still some lines are skipped while importing.

Can you advise me where can be a  problem or what I should check to debug this?

p.s. 
My full code looks like:

```
    try{
            $fileName =  $this->upload();               
            $rootDirectory = dirname(__FILE__);             
            $filePath = $rootDirectory.$fileName;                                                                                                                      
            $con = new PDO( LOCAL_DB_HOST, LOCAL_DB_USER, LOCAL_DB_PASS );  
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$filePath."' 
                    INTO TABLE r_vehicle_submodel 
                    CHARACTER SET UTF8
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
                    IGNORE 1 LINES ";      

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Data uploaded to MySQL <br>";
      }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $con->errorInfo();
      }
```

EDIT:

1. From that 29k lines it randomly pick which it insert and which not, its not like just first 14k.
2. Script doesn't timeout, it all actualy take like 5 sec max :)

Comment: Are you seeing the first 14k lines in the db? Or some random selection

Comment: Are the 29k lines really distinct? `IGNORE` ignores duplicates without warning AFAIK (is there a primary key? Is it correct?)

Comment: Hey guys, it's not first 14k, just random selection I didnt find the key why it skip some lines.

There is no primary key in table, IGNORE should skip just header or first line, or I'm WRONG?

Comment: You should specify the line endings in your statement.

Comment: Hi @Michael How the query should looks then? :)